# Bamboo builds with dependent .net projects

Tags: .net, iis, bitbucket, bamboo

We have a core library that is managed separately from our main application. The core library and main application are separate GIT repositories as well. The main application's solution is referencing the core library projects. The file strucutre is setup like this:

```
Source Code Folder    
     Core Library folder    
     Main Application Folder
```

The main application's solution is using relative paths to reference the core library:

```
..\CoreLibrary\Core.Domain\Core.Domain.csproj
```

I'm trying to figure out how best to setup Bamboo so the main application builds correctly and can be deployed. I have looked into using Bamboo dependencies, but its not the compiled core library the main app's solution is looking to build from.  I'm not finding much information of this topic with regards to .Net dependent projects.

Should I have both repositories downloaded by the job, the core library will be placed in a specific working directory, then download the main app repository into a working directly relative to the core? So, when the main app builds it can reference the projects correctly? I did not see an option for specifying a repository download location. Unless there is a better way of building multiple dependent solutions.

**Update**

I did find once I added the source control checkout task I could specify a checkout directory. This might be what I am looking for.

**Update 2**

Setting up the relative checkout directories worked. I also had to setup a separate task to ensure the Nuget packages were downloaded. You can find out more by reading a blog post at [blog.falafel.com](https://blog.falafel.com/msbuild-with-atlassian-bamboo/). I ran both nuget command lines in the same script. Fo good measure I made sure the core library was first in the list.

Comment: Some might argue that "managed separately" does not go well with "compiled together". If you decide on one of them (together *or* separate) you will have less problems along the way.

Comment: @nvoigt, If life were that easy I would not have had to post this question.